# Not all items appear in Multilist with Search field

Tags: solr, content-editor

```
Sitecore version: 9.1.1--SXA version: 1.8.1
```

I have a folder with this id `{E1349067-E456-4903-BE42-6897A4559CA8}` that contains 466 items from the same template, I tried to rebuild the `master index` to get the full items and executed the query against `Solr` and got only 105 items back

this is the query that I used:

```
StartSearchLocation={E1349067-E456-4903-BE42-6897A4559CA8}&TemplateFilter={2F4B9787-ACBB-4192-A2F2-6DA38CA0DE37}
```

and it returned around 45 items

the query for `Solr` is:

```
q=_path:(e1349067e4564903be426897a4559ca8) AND _template:(2f4b9787acbb4192a2f26da38ca0de37)
```

any idea how to return all items in the field?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issues with multilist with search fields, the primary issue we had was it was not using the master index, instead it was using the custom index we had which crawls though the start search location. If you have custom index, rebuild the custom index will fix this issue.

If you want to use sitecore_master_index instead, specify the index name in your query like this.

```
StartSearchLocation=query:../..&Filter=+_templatename:TemplateName&Filter=+_indexname:sitecore_master_index
```

Hope this helps